# TypeScript generic function that takes two arrays or two objects, not a mix

Tags: typescript

I'm writing an `extend` function in TypeScript which can either:

- Take two objects, in which case it updates the first with the keys/values of the second.
- Take two arrays, in which case it appends the elements of the second to the first.

i.e.

- `extend({a: 1}, {b: 2})  → {a: 1, b: 2}`
- `extend([1], [2]) → [1, 2]`

This function should take either two arrays or two objects, never one of each.

I'm trying to come up with the right type signature for it. Ideally it would be something like:

```js
function extend<A, B, StrOrNum extends (string|number)>(
    a: {[key: StrOrNum]: A},
    b: {[key: StrOrNum]: B}): {[key: StrOrNum]: A&B} {
  ..
}
```

`tsc` complains, however, that index signatures must be either `string` or `number`:

```
[ts] An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'.
(parameter) key: StrOrNum extends string | number
```

If I were writing a type definition file, I'd just define two overloads of the function. Can I do something similar when I'm implementing it? Or is this function just incoherent—this is the type system's way of telling me that I should split it into `extendObject` and `extendArray` functions?

Answer (score 0):

You might do something similar using options interfaces:

```
interface ObjectOptions<T> { a: {[key: string]: T}, b: {[key: string]: T} }
interface ArrayOptions<T> { a: Array<T>; b: Array<T>; }
function extend<T>(params: ObjectOptions<T>|ArrayOptions<T>) { }
extend({a:[1],b:{k:1}}); // error
```

In certain cases, you can also extend a class called `Foo` with an interface `Foo` that defines the overload, but this is seldom a good idea. All of this is more cumbersome than just having two distinct functions, like [`concat`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#concat) for arrays, and [`merge`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#merge) for the case of objects.

> Or is this function just incoherent—this is the type system's way of telling me...

Yes. An object-based map is a mapping to objects, but an array is also a mapping to objects. Your function should treat these two maps consistently - your operation on an array should not yield:

```
extend([1], [2]) → [1, 2]
```

but instead:

```
extend([1], [2]) → [2]
extend([1, 2], [7, undefined, 8]) → [7, 2, 8]
```

For new TypeScript code, if you're having trouble with overloads, prefer to create two distinct methods rather than trying to hack type checks into a single method. (The biggest benefit is hassle-free refactoring)